# How can I zoom out the lock screen on Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, lock-screen

How can I zoom out the lock screen which is wrongly zoomed in?

[image: photo of top of screen]

[image: photo of bottom of screen]

[image: photo of password entry]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just hover your mouse on the upper right corner of the window. You will see a down caret icon.
[image]

[image]

From this dropdown menu just turn off zoom option.